# getting linux to run on a car stereo device that runs WinCE

Tags: android, linux, windows-ce

I've a car stereo (Pioneer AppRadio2) that seems to have a ROM tha contains WindowsCE for MIPS.

Would it be possible to run Linux/Andriod on the device by flashing a linux type ROM to the device ?

If it is possible what would be the high level steps that need to be done to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pioneer does have a [mobile developer web site](http://www.appradiodev.com/) for AppRadio, but it isn't live yet, so it looks like Pioneer won't be an immediate help.

You need to determine if the bootloader is locked by some sort of digital signature or not.  If it is digitally signed and locked, you're going to have to either obtain a key from Pioneer or reverse engineer it.

Following that, use an embedded toolkit like [OpenEmbedded](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Main_Page) to create a Linux environment on the device.

Answer (score 1):

That wont be so easy. Actually it is meant to be a control station for android and iphone devices. so you could just use the android kit for your phone and control it from your appradio2 as for now. I know youre radio wouldnt be running the android itself but would display it and control it.

since it is quite new it will take some time for developers to "hack" it if it is possible. i have seen bounties on xda for example from people that would like what you are asking and other things.